# ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): setproxy() takes at most 7 arguments (8 given)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Both `gcloud auth login` and `gcloud compute --project XXX ssh --zone YYY ZZZ` printed the error message in the title.

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): setproxy() takes at most 7 arguments (8 given)

The `gcloud version` is

```
Google Cloud SDK 186.0.0
bq 2.0.28
core 2018.01.22
gsutil 4.28
```

`gcloud auth login` has worked before the upgrade to 186.0.0 (from 182.0.0). All of `gcloud` has worked some time previously. To double-check, the proxy has been set:

```
gcloud config set proxy/address 127.0.0.1
gcloud config set proxy/port 8080
gcloud config set proxy/type http
```

but this has not changed anything (proxy is set via environment variables anyways).

```
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

---

UPDATE: The error has persisted even after removing the config directory `~/.config/gcloud`. There's an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72407295.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, downgrading to 185 solved the issue:

Go to https://storage.cloud.google.com/cloud-sdk-release, type "google-cloud-sdk-185" into the search bar, download the file for your OS, unzip, etc. You need to use a new shell to unset the change to the `PATH` that `gcloud` did.

It [has been fixed in 187:](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72407295#comment10)

> We've found a fix; expect it in the 187.0.0 Cloud SDK release next week.

---

**Update** Version 187 has been released: Download at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned. This also gives the message

> To revert your SDK to the previously installed version, you may run:
>
> ```
> $ gcloud components update --version 185.0.0
> ```

after upgrade, so that could be used to revert as well, if similar problems occur.